# Data translation between 2 sql server databases with c #

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hi I'm importing lines from one database to another to use the code below but when I get to the datacreation point I get the following exception **Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll**

how do I solve this?

**Error Line:** `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataCreazione",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DataCreazione;`

**C# Code:**

```
string dbserver2 = textBox4.Text;
            string dbname2 = textBox1.Text;
            string dbusername2 = textBox2.Text;
            string dbpassword2 = textBox3.Text;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + dbserver2 + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname2 + ";User ID=" + dbusername2 + ";Password=" + dbpassword2 + "");
            conn.Open();
            String sql1 = "SELECT IdUtente,Longitudine,Latitudine,Stato,DataCreazione FROM dbo.Marcatura where IdMarcatura > 6661 order by convert(datetime, DataCreazione, 103) ASC";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            /*DB2*/
            string dbserver = textBox5.Text;
            string dbname = textBox8.Text;
            string dbusername = textBox7.Text;
            string dbpassword = textBox6.Text;

            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + dbserver + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + dbusername + ";Password=" + dbpassword + "");
            conn2.Open();
            int conta = 0;
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int IdUtente = int.Parse(dr["IdUtente"].ToString());
                        decimal Longitudine = decimal.Parse(dr["Longitudine"].ToString());
                        decimal Latitudine = decimal.Parse(dr["Latitudine"].ToString());
                        String Stato = dr["Stato"].ToString();
                        String DataCreazione = dr["DataCreazione"].ToString();
                        // MessageBox.Show("IdUtente: " + IdUtente + "\n Longitudine: " + Longitudine + "\n Latitudine" + Latitudine + "\n Stato: " + Stato + "\n DataCreazione: " + DataCreazione);
                        string queryfinal = "INSERT INTO Marcatura(IdUtente,Longitudine,Latitudine,Stato,DataCreazione) VALUES(@IdUtente,@Longitudine,@Latitudine,@Stato,@DataCreazione)";
                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(queryfinal, conn2);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUtente", IdUtente);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitudine", Longitudine);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitudine", Latitudine);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stato", Stato);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataCreazione", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DataCreazione; /* <--- ERROR LINE */
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        conta++;
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Totale errori: " + conta);
            }
```

Comment: Probably by not trying to stuff a string into a DateTime.

Comment: you will be better off using  `SqlBulkCopy` here instead of individual inserts. here is MSDN example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Do not use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

If `DataCreazione` is a `DateTime` column in both databases you can use the original value without converting it to `String`:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataCreazione", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dr["DataCreazione"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

`myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataCreazione", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DataCreazione;`

With :

`myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataCreazione",Convert.ToDateTime(DataCreazione));`